# Simple POST message to server

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to send a simple message(NSString) to my php script. I am trying to do a POST request. I am unable to do this and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone tell me my mistake?

Thank you!

**PHP Code**

```
 <?php

if($_POST['error'])
{
$date= time();
$error=$_POST['error'];
$message=$date." ".$error;

echo $message;

//Rest of code just writes to a log file
 ?>
```

**---------------------**

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"error=%@",serverError];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding                            allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/error.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSLog(@"responseData is %@", responseData);
```

Comment: Note that this question is not about Xcode.

Comment: what is the response? or there is no response at all? Try printing the error description just like you've printed the response data... you might get some idea.. if you dont, post the response/error in you question too...

Comment: @lukya So the response is that is not writing to the file and the NSLog is returning"ResponseData is <>" Thanks!

Comment: @Teddy13 After you call +sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:, what is the value of 'err'? Is it initialized? Like lukya said, can you print out the value of 'err'?

Comment: @JasonBarker I am not sure how to print the "err" but I fixed something in my php script that was giving an error (an extra comma). It is still not working but I have figured out it has something to do with the post statement sent from the app. responseData is now returning "<626c6168 68683133 36393732 36373636 20546869 73206973 20726561 6c6c7920 626164>"

Comment: @Teddy13 To output 'err', you can add a NSLog statement like: NSLog(@"err: %@", err);

Comment: Thanks Jason. I did that and it crashed on me saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Any other suggestions? Perhaps on those random numbers responseData is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"error=%@", serverError];`

rather than

`NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"error=%@", serverError];`